# Replacing dialog close button just Cross icon

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dialog

Im trying to replace jquery dialog close button just one icon, but cant manage to do that.
I have tried the different css formating that I have found here, but just dont succeed.

I have also tried to change the dialog settings, but with that, managed only to see part of the cross on top of the button (used red cross to see, that my icon will appear, not the dialog default one, which would be ok, if without that button in the background)

```
.ui-icon.ui-icon-red-deny{
    background-image: url("../Content/images/35x35/icon35-deny-red.png") ; 
}

$("#dialogInfo").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            create: function(event, ui) {
                var widget = $(this).dialog("widget");
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close span", widget).removeClass("ui-icon-closethick").addClass("ui-icon-red-deny");
            },
```

[Dialog close button to cross icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSaSO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to your CSS rule and make sure it does apply in every situation.

```
.ui-icon.ui-icon-red-deny{
     background-image: url("../Content/images/35x35/icon35-deny-red.png") !important; 
}
```

Comment: Tried that also. Dosent change anything. Still showing as the last image. What you mean by making sure? What I need to do?

Comment: Look with an inspector at all the classes that could be applied to your target and apply your rule to all those classes